# Average of DateTimeField Django

Tags: django, timestamp, average

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    ...
    a=models.IntegerField()
    timestamp=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want the average of timestamp field and when making a query:

```
Foo.objects.filter(a=1).values('timestamp','a').aggregate(Avg('timestamp'))
```

It's giving me an error:

```
'decimal.Decimal' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'
```

How can I fix this or how can I take the average of `DateTimeField`?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas         
from .models import *
k=Foo.objects.filter(a=1).values('timestamp')
li=[]  
for i in k:  
   li.append(i["timestamp"])  
df=pandas.DataFrame(data=li,columns=["date"])  
print(df["date"].mean())  
print(df["date"].median())
```